# Expand all parent nodes of a specific node in C# treeview

Tags: c#, treeview, treenode

I'm creating a recursive find method in C# `Treeview`, and I want to expand all parent nodes of the fined node. This is my code:

```
private void RecursivFindNode(RadTreeNodeCollection nodes, string nodeName2Find)
{
   foreach (RadTreeNode node in nodes)
   {
      if (node.Text.Contains(nodeName2Find))
       {
           node.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
           NodeExpand(node);
       }
       RecursivFindNode(node.Nodes);
    }

}

private void NodeExpand(RadTreeNode nodeExpand)
{
   while (nodeExpand != null)
   {
       nodeExpand.Expand();
       nodeExpand = nodeExpand.Parent;
    }
}
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.
```

I know I can't modify the item which is in a `foreach loop`. So how can I make it work?

Comment: Why does the one method, that by name should only be "finding" nodes (or rather *one* node?), also expand them/it? Have it just return the found node(s). And then have a third method, that calls "find" and after that calls "expand". Also, it might be better to have the search text as input parameter, rather than retrieve it from an obscure textbox (I assume). And last, If you still get that error, you might want to materialize the collection in the foreach to a second one (`nodes.ToList()` with Linq for example) and see if that helps.

Comment: Try `foreach (var node in nodes.OfType<RadTreeNode>().ToArray()`

Comment: @Vlad Thanks! it is my solution!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as [@Vlad](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3383776/vlad) suggested, I changed my `foreach` to this:

```
foreach (var node in nodes.OfType<RadTreeNode>().ToArray())
```

And now everything works fine. :)